# Where to continue coding after created intent?

Tags: java, android

I use an intent to call a new class and show a new layout with some buttons on.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
                setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

After this i want to show/hide some buttons on the second (game) layout.

i try to find the button:

```
button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
```

The thing is when i debug it never goes into the new Game-class and in my Main it can´t find my buttons because they are on the other layout.. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
startActivity(intent);  //<<<<<<< start Activity here
setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

if you want to move from MainActivity class (Activity) to Game.class (Activity)

Answer (score 0):

You should move the initilization of the buttons to the onCreate method of Game Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    .
    .
    .
    button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
}
```